# ic_launcher error while building .apk

Tags: launcher

I am getting the below error when trying to build my `.apk`. I usually have programmers working for me on my apps, but this one I have tried to figure out on my own. No surprises there, I could not.

[image]

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localised guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: What language/system is this? Is this [tag:java] and [tag:android]? Please retag if so.